# Actualizar datos con AJAX PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

Estoy tratando de hacer un `update` sin tener que actualizar la página. Pero estoy tratando de aprender y entender cómo usar `AJAX`. Por el momento hice esto, no funciona y no se como terminarlo.

Archivo prueba.php

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cbec68f37d.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#change").keyup(function(){
    var parametros="change="+$(this).val()
    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url: 'update.php',
        type:  'GET',
        beforeSend: function () {},
            success:  function (response) {    
            $(".salida").html(response);
        },
        error:function(){
            alert("error")
        }
    });
})
})
</script>

<div class="container w-75 p-5">
<h3 class="mb-4">Activar y desactivar</h3>
<?php
$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM proyectos");
while ($fila = $list->fetch()) {
if($fila['pestado'] == '0') {
?>
<p>
Activo <span class="text-primary" id="change"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i></a></span>
</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p>
Inactivo <span class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i></span>
</p>
<?php } } ?>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Archivo update.php

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

$code = $_GET['@'];

$sql = "UPDATE proyectos SET pestado = '1' WHERE idp = '".$code."'";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                                   
$stmt->execute();

//echo 'Bien!';
?>
```

En `Activo <span class="text-primary" id="change"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i></a></span>` agregue el `id="change"`, y se que falta algo que iría en `href="#"`, pero no se que es por falta de conocimiento.

Me gustaria que me ayuden a entender cómo utilizar esto porque no lo entiendo, me refiero a que no se como funciona `AJAX` con `Jquery` aunque mi idea es usar solo `JavaScript`.

Agradezco de antemano.

Comment: Ahora ya puedo comentar ^^ . Puedo ayudarte con mucho gusto a realizar lo que buscas y debido al código que muestras específicamente no tiene ninguna función.

Debes mostrar la información de alguna manera para saber que quieres actualizar. Te propongo darte un ejemplo explicándote el funcionamiento, paso por paso. desde traer los datos, hasta actualizarlos usando ajax/jquery php y json. Te sirve? o necesitas específicamente ese código? (lo digo ya que entiendo que quieres aprender el funcionamiento y tratas de hacerlo)

Comment: Todo me sirve, pero tambien quiero entenderlo, aprender como se hace bien para avanzar con este tema que para mi es un tabu. Gracias!

Comment: ok dame un momento

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Aqui tengo la explicacion detallada para ejecicio y problema planteado.**

**Primero** voy a empezar con las correcciones para saber la razon del porque no esta funcionando:

1) Se está creando los check  de activo con un identificador id=”change” lo cual no se debe hacer, porque un id es único por cada etiqueta, regla del HTML 5

```
Activo <span class="text-primary" id="change"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i></a></span>
```

2) El evento `keyup()` para JQuery es usado para escuchar el teclado al solar la tecla. (se recomienda usar `click()`
Cambiar por:

```
$(".change").click(function(){
```

3) Se debe cambiar el selector del evento en JQuery para que escuche a todo los  activos usando tipo clase:

```
$("#change")
```

Cambiar por:

```
$(".change")
```

4) Poner la coma al final de los  bloques `})`

```
$(".change").keyup(function(){
```

Cambiar por:

```
$(".change").click(function(){
```

5) Se recomienda colocar la carga de las librerías antes del codigo a ejecutar para que se puede interpretar la secuencia de la instrucciones.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

6) Para hacer la actualización del registro se necesita colocar un identificador de registro que identifique a quien pertenece ese ítem, el cual puede ser colocado en un atributo personalizado en la etiqueta.**Ejemplo: idp**

```
<p>
Activo <span class="text-primary change" idp="<?= $fila['idp']; ?>"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i></a></span>
</p>
```

7) No se esta pasando correctamente en el archivo actualizar el valor **idp**, por lo tanto el SQL no puede saber a que registro actualizar.

**$code = $_GET['@'];**

Ahora

**$code = $_GET['idp'];**

8) Se debe enviar una respuesta al ser ejecutado la actualización en el archivo update.php, dicha respuesta puede ser usa salida tipo echo que será leida por el AJAX posteriormente.

**echo 'Activo idp' . $code;**

9) Este codigo no tiene utilidad por que se usa el método `val()` para obtener valor de una etiqueta input y no de un span,  no esta pasando los parámetros en forma correcta al AJAX.

```
var parametros="change="+$(this).val()
```

10) Se usara el metodo post para pasar los datos via AJAX, es mas seguro y se puede enviar mas informacion a futuro.

```
type:  'POST',
```

11) La data que será enviada por el Ajax es de esta forma:

```
data: {"parametro1" : "valor1", "parametro2" : "valor2"},
```

12) La etiqueta “.salida” no existe para mostrar el resultado del codigo hay que crearla.

```
$(".salida").html(response);
```

13) Quitar esta carga de librería y usar el CDN de JQuery de google. (esta incompleto y no corre AJAX)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Cambiar por este:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

14) Cambiar el método para recibir los datos en el archivo update.php

```
$code = $_GET['idp'];
```

Por este otro

```
$_POST['idp'];
```

15) Comentar la sintaxis de eco para la conexión exitosa en el archivo: connet.php

// echo "Connected successfully";

**EXPLICACION DEL CODIGO YA ESTA FUNCIONANDO CON AJAX:**

1) ARCHIVO: **connect.php**

Se creo una conexión a la base de datos a través de método PDO que es orientado a objetos.

Se declara los valores en la variables de conexión respectiva.

```
  // parametros de conexion
  $host ="localhost";
  $user ="grafimar_admin";
  $password ="anybody2015"; 
  $database = "pruebas";
```

Se usa el `try { } catch` para captura el error de conexión en caso de falla.

La conexion se establece creando una instancia del objeto **PDO** con el nombre de **$conn**.

```
$conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user,  $password);
```

Se configura los parametros del modo expecion de errores

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

2) ARCHIVO: **update.php**

Este archive es una simple rutina para actualizar registros.

Aquí se carga la conexión solamente una vez

```
require_once 'connect.php';
```

Se recibe el valor del nombre de variable “idp” a travez de un método POST.

```
$code = $_POST['idp'];
```

Hacemos la sintaxis de actualización del registro y se pasa el valor de idp para buscar el registro especifico  y se ponde el valor del campo **pestado = 1**

```
$sql = "UPDATE proyectos SET pestado = '1' WHERE idp = '".$code."'";
```

Preparamos la conexión para ejecutar el comando SQL y se procede a su ejecución.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                                   
$stmt->execute();
```

Enviamos una respuesta en pantalla por hacer actualizado el registro la cual consiste en *“Activo “+  numero del idp*

```
echo 'Activo idp' . $code;
```

**EXPLICACION DEL CODIGO:**

3) ARCHIVO: **actualizar.php**

Se cargan las librerías al principio para poder ejecutar sus instrucciones.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Con esta instrucción obliga a  terminar la carga de la pagina se para ejecutar el codigo jquery o javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Se escucha el evento del click botón derecho del mouse para la clase .chanse

```
$(".change").click(function(){
```

Capturamos el valor del atributo correspondiente con la etiqueta que tiene la clase **“change”** la cual es el

```
var idp = $(this).attr('idp'); // valor del idp 
            console.log(idp); // reporte por consola
```

Construimos la estrutura para pasar los datos mediante AJAX el cual usa la sintaxis:

```
{“llave”: “valor”}

var parametros={"idp":idp}; // construccion del parametro para enviar al AJAX
```

Aquí el nombre de la variable será idp y su valor será obtenido por la variable idp que recibió el valor del atributo con el mismo nombre.

```
// sintaxis para cambiar la clase de la etiqueta hijo de span
        $(this).children().children().removeClass( "fa-toggle-on" ).addClass( "fa-toggle-off");
```

2) Para cambiar el estado del botón cambiamos su atributo mediante la remoción de la clase y luego la colocación de una nueva clase. En este caso el botón es el nieto de la etiqueta  por eso se hace dos niveles de children().

3) Ahora ejecutamos el codigo **AJAX:**  pasando los parámetros correspondientes:

**Data**: (son los datos que recibirá el otro archivo para trabajar)

**url:** (es la ruta y nombre del archivo)

**type:** Se usa el método POST por ser mas seguro y practico.

**beforeSend:** function () {}

Esta funcion se ejecuta antes de realizar la petición de AJAX, es util para aviso para el usuario o validaciones.

**success:**  function (response) {}

Aquí se ha ejecutado satisfactoriamente el AJAX y se recibe la respuesta del archivo a través de la variable responde, en este caso será recibido 'Activo idp'.

```
$(".salida").html(response);
```

Mostrarmos el contenido de la salida a la etiqueta con clase “salida”

```
 setTimeout(() => {
                            $(".salida").empty(); // limpiar salida
                        }, 2000);
```

Se usa para borrar el contenido de la etiqueta  de clase “salida” despues de 2000 ms

```
 error:function(){
                        alert("error")
                    }
```

En caso de fallo en la comunicación con AJAX se ejecuta este bloque de codigo.

**CUERPO DEL ARCHIVO**

```
require_once 'connect.php';
```

Se carga una sola vez la conexión.

```
$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM proyectos");
```

Se hace la consulta de SQL para todos los registros.

```
while ($fila = $list->fetch()) {}
```

Usamos el while para hacer un recorrido de todos los registro uno a uno, tomando los datos a través de la variable **$fila.**

```
if($fila['pestado'] == '0') {
Si el valor del campo pestado=0 entonces muestra el botón en modo ACTIVO.
<p>
Activo <span class="text-primary change" idp="<?= $fila['idp']; ?>"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i></a></span>
</p>
```

Aquí se ha agregado un atributo propio llamado idp el cual va a contener el **id** que corresponde con ese registro y sirve para referenciarlo cuando se realice el evento del click.

```
<p>
Inactivo <span class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i></span>
</p>
```

En caso de que pestado tenga otro valor coloca el estado del botón en Inactivo.

```
<h5 class="salida"></h5>
```

Salida que será llevada con el reporte de AJAX

AJUNTO LOS ARCHIVOS:

**Archivo connect.php**

```
    <?php

      // parametros de conexion
      $host ="localhost";
      $user ="grafimar_admin";
      $password ="anybody2015"; 
      $database = "pruebas";

      // CONEXION A LA BD POR PDO
        try {
            $conn= new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $user,  $password);
            // set the PDO error mode to exception
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            // echo "Connected successfully"; 
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
            echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

    ?>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    **Archivo update.php**

```
    <?php
    require_once 'connect.php';

    $code = $_POST['idp'];

    $sql = "UPDATE proyectos SET pestado = '1' WHERE idp = '".$code."'";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);                                   
    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'Activo idp' . $code;
    ?>
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    **Archivo actualizar.php**

```
<head>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/cbec68f37d.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- codigo a ejecutar -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".change").click(function(){

            var idp = $(this).attr('idp'); // valor del idp 
            console.log(idp); // reporte por consola
            var parametros={"idp":idp}; // construccion del parametro para enviar al AJAX
            // sintaxis para cambiar la clase de la etiqueta hijo de span
            $(this).children().children().removeClass( "fa-toggle-on" ).addClass( "fa-toggle-off");                   
                    $.ajax({
                        data: parametros,
                        url: 'update.php',
                        type:  'POST',
                        beforeSend: function () {},
                            success:  function (response) {    
                            $(".salida").html(response);

                            setTimeout(() => {
                                $(".salida").empty(); // limpiar salida
                            }, 2000);
                        },
                        error:function(){
                            alert("error")
                        }
                    }); // fin de ajax/ 
        }); // fin de click 
}); // fin de document ready

</script>

<div class="container w-75 p-5">
<h3 class="mb-4">Activar y desactivar</h3>

<?php
// conectar ala BD
require_once 'connect.php';
?> 

<?php
 // carga de elementos (CONSULTA BD)
$list = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM proyectos");

while ($fila = $list->fetch()) {
if($fila['pestado'] == '0') {
?>
<p>
Activo <span class="text-primary change" idp="<?= $fila['idp']; ?>"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-toggle-on"></i></a></span>
</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<p>
Inactivo <span class="text-muted"><i class="fas fa-toggle-off"></i></span>
</p>
<?php } } ?>
</div>

<h5 class="salida"></h5>
</body>
</html>
```

**Imagenes de pantallas Ejecutando el programa:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen de la Tabla de base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imagen despues de Correr el Programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultado y Cambio en la Tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estrutura de la tabla con la cual se probo el codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mis felicitaciones a la explicación, de las mejores que e visto en SO.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alexander, ahora entiendo mas como utilizar `AJAX` para poder resolver a futuro los problemas de conocimiento. Muchas gracias nuevamente! Voy a ser honesto, no copie el codigo ya que quiero hacerlo con las recomendaciones que me has dado. Trabajo muy poco con JavaScript, JQuery y AJAX, pero tengo pensado hacer un curso o verlo para aprender mas!

Answer (score 3):

**Espero ser de ayuda**

Este ejemplo es funcional. Comento cada paso y dejo console.log para que descomentes y puedas ir viendo cada respuesta del servidor como variables. Solo crea la base de datos como te dejo escrito luego copy y paste.

Como te mencione anteriormente la idea es ver la información que vas a actualizar ya que no tendría sentido. El ejemplo consiste en mostrar información existente, imprimirla para editar y actualizar al enviarla.
Cualquier duda estoy atento broda :)
Crea la base de datos. Use mysql!! y listo.
`BD: champions`
`TABLA: equipo`

**HTML: vistaJugadores.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JUGADORES</title>
    <!--IMPORTANTE. SCRIPT DE JQ ULTIMA VERSIÓN PARA USAR AJAX (DEBES DESCARGARLO Y CAMBIA LA RUTA COMO GUSTES)-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jugadores.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>
        Actualizar datos usando Php/JQ/Ajax/Html
    </h3>
    <!--FORMULARIO PARA ACTUALIZAR DATOS-->
    <form id="formJugadores">
        <!--Inpute no visible. Evita editar el id y no realizar la actualización-->
        <input type="hidden" id="id">
        <input type="text" id="apellido">
        <input type="text" id="camiseta" maxlength="2">
        <button id="btn">ACTUALIZAR</button>
    </form>

    <!--TABLA PARA MOSTRAR DATOS-->
    <div class="contentTable">
        <table border>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido</th>
                <th>Camiseta</th>
                <th>Actualizar</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="bodyTable">
                <!--AQUI SE MUESTRAN TODOS LOS DATOS EXISTENTES EN LA BD 
                POR MEDIO DE LA PETICIÓN AJAX-->
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JQ/AJAX: jugadores.js**

```
//MOSTRAR DATOS DE BD

//Inicia la  funcion al abrir la página
$(document).ready(function() {
    jugadores();//ejecucion de la  función

    function jugadores(){//Funcion para mostrar todos los datos existentes
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET', //GET para traer información
            url: 'jugadores.php', //Archivo de consulta
            success: function(response){//Si hay exito espera rta del svr
                //console.log(response);
                let jugador = JSON.parse(response);//Archivo JSON a string (respuesta)
                let plantilla = ''//Variable vacía para mostrar los datos

                // iteramos sobre todos arreglos
                jugador.forEach(jugadores =>{
                    //html para mostrar en tabla: selección de la función jugadores + el nombre del array del backend(jugadores.php)
                    plantilla +=`
                        <tr player=${jugadores.id}>
                            <td>${jugadores.id}</td>
                            <td>${jugadores.apellido}</td>
                            <td>${jugadores.camiseta}</td>
                            <td><input class="actualizar" type="image" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/131901/isolated/lists/30a7829a3622fd3b61b12fcc47391cb0-recargar-el-icono-del-circulo-de-la-flecha.png" width="50px" heigth="50px"></td>
                        </tr>
                    `
                });
                $('#bodyTable').html(plantilla);//Tabla para mostrar datos
            }
        })
    }

    //IMPRIMIR DATOS PARA ACTUALIZAR

    //Seleccion del botón actualizar por el evento click
    $(document).on('click', '.actualizar', function(){
        //acceso hasta el id que esta en la fila, osea, el tr
        let actualizar = $(this)[0].parentElement.parentElement;
        //Asignamción al tr de un atributo (backend)
        let id = $(actualizar).attr('player');
        //console.log(id);
        $.ajax({
            url:'consultaActualizacion.php', 
            data: {id},
            type: 'POST', 
            success: function(response){
                //console.log(response);
                let jugador = JSON.parse(response);
                let plantillaId = '';
                let plantillaApellido = '';
                let plantillaCamiseta = '';

                jugador.forEach(jugadores=>{
                    plantillaId +=`${jugadores.id}`
                });
                //console.log(plantillaNombre);
                jugador.forEach(jugadores=>{
                    plantillaApellido +=`${jugadores.apellido}`
                });
                //console.log(plantillaApellido);
                jugador.forEach(jugadores=>{
                    plantillaCamiseta +=`${jugadores.camiseta}`
                });
                //console.log(plantillaCamiseta);
                $('#id').val(plantillaId); //input con id: nombre
                $('#apellido').val(plantillaApellido);//input con id: apellido
                $('#camiseta').val(plantillaCamiseta);//input con id: camiseta
            }
        });
    });

    //ACTUALIZAR DATOS

    //Seleccion del formulario y se aplica su evento submit (envío)
    $('#formJugadores').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();//No permite refrescar la pagina al presionar el botón
        const datos = {//Guarda los valores de los inputs en una constante para enviarla al backend(actualizar.php)
            id: $('#id').val(),//Valor del input con id = id (no visible)
            apellido: $('#apellido').val(),//Valor del input con id = apellido
            camiseta: $('#camiseta').val(),//Valor del input con id = camiseta
        };
        //Envío la constante al backend 
        $.post('actualizar.php', datos, function(response){
            jugadores();//Retoma la funcion, para refrescar el navegador(permite ver el cambio al instante en la tabla)
            $('#formJugadores').trigger('reset');//Reset a los inputs cuando se lanzaa la actualización
        });
    });
});
```

**CONSULTAS PHP**
Los datos que se pidieron y se enviaron al backend.

**CONEXION A LA BD:bd.php**

```
<?php
    //modifica como necesites
    $bdatos = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","rootroot", "champions");
    if (!$bdatos) {
        die('error de consulta'.mysqli_error($bdatos));
    }
  ?>
```

**PHP: jugadores.php (vista general de los datos existentes)**

```
<?php
    //conexión a BD
    include 'bd.php';
    //Consulta a BD
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM equipo";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($bdatos, $consulta);
    if (!$resultado) {
        die('error de consulta'.mysqli_error($bdatos));
    }
    //Var tipo array para tranformar en arreglo
    $json = array();
    while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        //Se itera sobre toda la tabla, asignando una propidad y el valor es cada campo de la base de datos
        $json[] = array(
            'id' => $filas['id'],
            'apellido' => $filas['apellido'],
            'camiseta' => $filas['camiseta']
        );
    }
    $texto = json_encode($json);//Tranforma a JSON la información
    echo $texto;
?>
```

**PHP: consultaActualizacion.php (muestra los datos en los inputs)**

```
<?php
    include 'bd.php';

    $id = $_POST['id']; //variable que envia la petición ajax
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM equipo WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($bdatos, $consulta);

    if (!$resultado) {
            die('error de consulta'.mysqli_error($bdatos));
    }

    //Var tipo array para tranformar en arreglo
        $json = array();
    while ($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {
        //Se itera sobre todos, asignando una propidad y el valor son los campos de la BD
        $json[] = array(
            'id' => $filas['id'],
            'apellido' => $filas['apellido'],
            'camiseta' => $filas['camiseta']
        );
    }
    $texto = json_encode($json);//Tranforma a JSON la información
    echo $texto;
?>
```

**PHP: actualizar.php (Actualiza los datos una vez enviados)**

```
<?php
    include 'bd.php';

    //datos enviados por ajax
    $id = $_POST['id']; 
    $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
    $camiseta = $_POST['camiseta'];

    //Actualización de los campos de la BD dependiendo del ID (llave primaria PK)
    $consulta = "UPDATE equipo SET apellido = '$apellido', camiseta = '$camiseta' WHERE id = '$id'";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($bdatos, $consulta);

    if (!$resultado) {
        die('Error de actualizacion'.mysqli_error($bdatos));
            //puedes mostrar lo que gustes y como quieras
    }
    echo "actualizacion exitosa";
    //puedes mostrar lo que gustes y como quieras*/

?>
```

**CSS: estilo.css**

```
body{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    transform: translateY(25%);
}

h3{
    font-family: arial;
}
.contentTable{
    margin-top: 5vh;
}
#formJugadores #btn{
    outline: none;
}
table td{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero me siento estafado. No pedi un sistema, pedi al menos entender un poco como funciona `ajax`, esto no me quita las dudas. Gracias por tu tiempo, pero no es lo que estoy buscando. Ya vi sistemas hechos en la web, tambien podria bajarlos y listo, pero no el objetivo de la pregunta.

Comment: No es una respuesta valida. Tendrias que reportar al usuario o la pregunta!

Comment: Alcanza con votar negativamente la respuesta si esta no responde la pregunta. Los comunidad entera debe decidir respecto de la respuesta. No hay nada que reportar sobre la misma.

Comment: Sin embargo, tengan en cuenta que no es una mala respuesta, por mas que tenga el contenido equivocado. (en realidad es un ejemplo funcional, sin que agregue nada mas). Tal vez alcance con agradecer y no hacer nada mas.

Comment: mafu quien pregunto no quiere el codigo, si no entender como usar ajax en su sistema. No en cualquier sistema.

Comment: @gbianchi gracias y le he agradecido a **mafu** por su tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que quieres una explicacion o flujo de como hacerlo, entoces mira, lo que puedes hacer es obtener el nodo donde fue clickeado, ¿para qué? lo modificaras antes de hacer la peticion o despues de ella, necesitas dicho nodo para unicamente modificar este.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('click', '.span', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
    // con esto tienes el id
    var a=$(this).attr('id');
    $.get("update",{id:a},function(r){console.log(r)});
  })
})
```

`.span` puede se `th`,`div` o al que le pones `clase` a todos tus registro e `id` para que las pierdas al recorrer la lista.

si desdea modificar despues de la funcion

```
$.get("update",{id:a},function(r){console.log(r)});
```

puedes mandar mas para

```
{id:a}
```

esta es respuesta del servidor, si no tienes, puedes no ponerlo

```
    function(r){console.log(r)}
```

quiza lo necesitas para una notificacion

`JQuery` se ejecuta la peticion internamente, asi nunca se actulizará

o mejor puedes usar esta libreria

> https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html