# Ejecutar función PHP con Ajax?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Tengo el siguiente problema:
(No voy a colocar código ya que no he trabajado con Ajax)

Tengo un sitio web (hecho en wordpress) en el menú tengo un logOut, necesito que al darle click al logOut, se ejecute una función PHP, he leído en varios lados y si (uno trabaja del lado del servidor y otro del lado del cliente) la cuestión es que he logrado mandar un mensaje desde PHP, pero no una función mas compleja.

```
$log = "insert into bitacora (accion,created_at) values ('Log Out',now())";
        $rlog = $conn->query($log);
```

como puedo hacer que ejecute esta consulta cuando le doy click en Log Out?

Comment: esta es una pregunta muy básica, eso significa que no has buscado aún nada de información, comienza intentandolo hacerlo tú mismo y cuando tengas alguna duda realiza la pregunta

Comment: Ya he buscado, por eso escribí ( he leído en varios lados), si es muy básico, talvez puedas compartirme una idea de cómo lo harías tu

Comment: aqui hay una [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/288018/actualizar-datos-con-ajax-php-y-mysql) similar

Comment: Si como dices ya lograste enviar un mensaje a PHP, es lo mismo, sólo que en vez del mensaje llamas ahora a la función. Partiendo de ese código con el que enviaste el mensaje puedes ahora intentar ejecutar la función y si tienes problemas puedes compartirlo aquí indicando el error en concreto, etc. Además, como ya dijo @ReneLimon, aquí hay decenas de preguntas/respuestas sobre Ajax.

Comment: Les comparto el código:   function salir(){
    echo 'Hola';
}

?>
<html>
    <script>
        function clic(){
            document.write('<?php salir(); ?>');
        }
    </script>
</html>.                            este código me muestra el mensaje 'Hola', pero si quiero hacer esto dentro de la funcion salir $log = "insert into bitacora (id_usuario,accion,created_at) values (7,'Log Out',now())";
    $rlog = $conn->query($log); No hace nada, tampoco me muestra un error. tengo los datos de conexion y funciona adecuadamente.

Comment: Ok, pero ese código ocurre todo en el mismo contexto. Ajax es otra cosa, se trata de comunicar entre el cliente y el servidor. Para eso, generalmente recoges datos desde el cliente y lo pasas al servidor. Los datos viajan al servidor, éste los procesa y te devuelve una respuesta la cual puedes mostrar en el cliente si quieres, actualizando cualquier elemento del mismo, todo eso sin refrescar la página. Pero OJO: el archivo de servidor al que mandas los datos es otro distinto del archivo actual, que se indica en el parámetro `url` de Ajax. Aquí hay varios ejemplos que explican eso.

Comment: [Aquí hay una respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/117876/29967) donde he tratado de explicar con detalle cómo funciona Ajax. Allí se muestra una petición Ajax básica que manda datos al servidor. En el servidor se ejecuta una función que hace un `SELECT` en la BD (es lo mismo que quieres, sólo que en tu caso sería un `INSERT`. )

Comment: Si, sé que ajax es otra cosa, pero coloqué esto, porque por lo que quiero hacer, en teoría solo con ajax podría haberlo solucionado, pero como puedo hacer que se ejecute una función php cuando yo dé click en un link, boton, etc? ya que eso es lo que quiero realmente.

Comment: Le pones un listener al botón o enlace en cuestión y lanzas la petición Ajax desde el `onclick`. No le veo mayor dificultad a eso. ¿Qué dificultad tienes tú en concreto?

Comment: @A.Cedano como comenté en el último mensaje, al ejecutar esto: <?php function salir(){
    
    // DB connection
 
    $out = "insert into bitacora (id_usuario,accion,created_at) values (7,'Log Out',now());";
     $rout = $con->query($out);
}
?>

<html>
    <script>
        function clic(){
            document.write('<?php salir() ?> ');
        }
    </script>
</html>            No ejecuta el query

Comment: @MauEspaña Coincido con Rene Limon, la pregunta que te compartió podría ayudarte. Otro consejo es que cuando compartes código debes hacerlo [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/329241/edit) además tabularlo bien, y no en un comentario. De esta manera se puede entender mejor.